# Run jquery in all breakpoints except desktop

Tags: jquery, size, breakpoints, desktop

I only have a minimal code knowledge and I'm trying to achieve something. I only want this to work on smaller devices--basically less than desktop size. this is the code I have

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
     $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
  } else {
     $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});

 $('.nav-background, .nav__link, .primary-button').click(function() {
  $( ".menu-button" ).click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are like a thousand ways to do this, as u dont seem to use any css framework that gives u the "breakpoints" and "smaller than desktop" is very unprecise, i´ll show u one way with css and javascript

in your html just have an empty element with a specific id, for example

```
<div id="resolution_check"></div>
```

in your css you define a media query and your breakpoint and set this element to display none when width is smaller. e.g

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #resolution_check { display: none; }
}
```

in your javascript u can now check if this element is set to display none, and if so, the users resolution is smaller than 761px

```
var small_screen = $('#resolution_check').css('display')=='none';
```

below will follow your code in which you can check the var above, eg:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
   if(!small_screen){ // if NOT small screen return
     return false; 
   }
 ...
```

further, on resize event you need to set small_screen again because the width changed